Register a contribution and attach it to the membership
I have a lifetime membership: it concerns shares in the organisation that a user can buy.
From the backend I would like to register a contribution and attach it to the membership. How can I do this?
I know that exists the extension membershippayment (see this comment), but it seems abandoned. Can we do so and update it? Or do you recommend another way?
Thank you

You are right that the membership payment extension hasn't been updated in a while but we have it installed on a site and it is still working fine as far as I'm aware.
You need to apply this PR though to improve compatibility with recent CiviCRM and PHP versions: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.membershippayment/pull/7
UPDATE: version 1.2 has been released which should work with the current versions of CiviCRM. I've tested with CiviCRM 5.75

Many thanks William, it was just what I needed.

Glad to be of help!

Can you just Add/Renew a membership and record a payment?

A contact can have only one membership for this type and make "n" contributions at different times. I cannot use "Renew membership" because the renew process has not pricesets. I have to registrer the quantity of shares that the contact buys.
